# Is SVG suitable to display 5000 images?

Tags: user-interface, svg

I want to display 5000 plus images in a single page, each image will be exactly 100 x 100. Is SVG a better approach than using a normal DIV tag to map these images? Or is there a better alternative to do this?

Comment: You're asking if you should use `svg` or `div`? The two aren't really comparable

Comment: @WesFoster I had SVG in mind but the question is can i load 5000 plus images in a page without having performance issues? Is SVG good or should i look into something else?

Comment: You'd be better off using raster images, compressed at their smallest. The performance will depend on the filesize of the images. This question isn't really a fit for StackOverflow, however.

Comment: Are you talking about using an image map? like 100x100 images all together as one large image? or are you talking about a mosaic of individual images?

Comment: Your question is too broad and not clear enough. I suggest you rewrite it (possibly add some code or pseudocode examples) and make it clear exactly what is the problem you are trying to solve. Are these actual raster images you want to add? Or are you considering the use of SVG vector graphics (one file or many files) to replace them? Depending on the complexity of your images (are they drawings, photos, logos, fonts?) SVG may or may not be a good solution.